# Dynamic max-Value in AngularUI/ UI Bootstrap progressbar directive

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular UI/UI Bootstrap's Progressbar directive (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) like so:

```
<progressbar max="questions.length" value="currentQuestion">
   {{currentQuestion}} von {{questions.length}} Fragen
</progressbar>
```

Both `questions` and `currentQuestion` are in the scope of the enclosing controller. The problem is, that `questions` get loaded dynamically from a backend and available only after some milliseconds have passed.

However, I found out that if `questions.length` is not set at the very moment the view (in which `<progressbar>` is embedded in) is "compiled", the progressbar does not get displayed correctly. If I set `questions = [1,2,3]` in my controller, it is displayed correctly, but with a static `max` of 3 which isn't changed, even after `questions` have been loaded. I do not know upfront how long `questions` will be, this should be thus dynamic. On the other hand, the `value` attribute can be changed dynamically and this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround in the meantime, as suggested by @johnnyaug on https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1547

```
<progressbar max="100" value="( currentQuestion * 100 ) / questions.length"></progressbar>
```